# Grafana alert when change between two data points is high

Tags: grafana

I have a Grafana graph with data coming in from Prometheus.  I'm trying to get an alert set up so that if the change over one minute (or so, I'm flexible) is over 60, an email notification goes out.  I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that suggests a way to do this, or if it's possible at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in the delta between points you can can plot the [derivative()](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.derivative) of your series, and alert on that.

Comment: I'm afraid I need the actual data on the graph; I've just been asked to provide an alert when it increases rapidly.

Comment: Also, I'm still learning the vocabulary so I might be wrong--but I'm using Prometheus; does Graphite stuff apply?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you're using prometheus, not sure what the options are in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The Prometheus [sum_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#aggregation-_over_time) or [rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#rate) functions are probably what you are looking for. There is also a [deriv](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#deriv()) function.

The [Grafana demo site](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/prometheus-demo-dashboard?refresh=5m&orgId=1) has some Prometheus query examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [delta](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) function. For example, the following query returns non-empty result (aka alert) when the metric `foo` increased by more than 60 during the last minute (see `[1m]` in square brackets):

```
delta(foo[1m]) > 60
```

It is possible to use any supported time duration in square brackets (aka lookbehind window) for caclulating the metric delta on different intervals. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).